# Speed up nested draws from multivariate normal where each draw has different mean vector in r

Tags: r, lapply

As part of a model fitting algorithm I need to take multiple draws from a multivariate normal distribution.

The draws have a nested structure, so for the model fitting algorithm I need to take e.g. 1000 draws for 5 units, each of which contains 500 units.  So in total 1000 * 5 * 500 draws in this example.  For each of the 1000 draws, the covariance matrix `sigma` for the multivariate distribution will be different.  For each of the 5*500 units within the 1000 draws, the mean vector `mu` will be different.

I've coded up an example below that firstly sets up example data of the structure I'm interested in, and then generates the draws in the format I need.

```
#set up
library(mvnfast) #for rmvn function

nPar<-1000
K<-5
n<-rep(500,K)
mu<-lapply(1:nPar,function(u){
  lapply(1:K,function(v){
    do.call(rbind,lapply(1:n[v],function(w){
      runif(1)*c(0.3,0.5)
    }))
  })
})
sigmamats<-lapply(1:nPar,function(u){
  runif(1)*matrix(c(0.5,0.1,0.1,0.5),nrow=2,ncol=2)
})

#code needing speeding up
system.time(test<-lapply(1:nPar,function(u){
  lapply(1:K,function(v){
    do.call(rbind,lapply(1:n[v],function(w){
      rmvn(n=1,
           mu=mu[[u]][[v]][w,],
           sigma=sigmamats[[u]])
    }))
  })
}))
# user     system elapsed 
# 122.01   78.49  204.06
```

I've tried a few different rearrangements (e.g. using rbind first, and removing the `w` layer of nesting, so that the second lapply runs from 1 to 2500 in this example, but this did not speed up the code much at all.

I need to cut down this time, as this will be evaluated at least 200 times in my model fitting algorithm.  The dimensions at each level (`nPar`, `K`, `n`) can change depending on the data being evaluated.

Any advice for how to speed this up would be appreciated.

EDIT profiling results:

```
Rprof(tmp<-tempfile())
test<-lapply(1:nPar,function(u){
   lapply(1:K,function(v){
     do.call(rbind,lapply(1:n[v],function(w){
       rmvn(n=1,
            mu=mu[[u]][[v]][w,],
            sigma=sigmamats[[u]])
     }))
   })
 })
 Rprof()
 summaryRprof(tmp)
$by.self
                 self.time self.pct total.time
".Call"             153.16    75.27     161.84
"rmvn"               21.32    10.48     190.90
"matrix"              6.20     3.05       6.46
"FUN"                 5.44     2.67     203.48
"lapply"              4.96     2.44     203.48
"getCallingDLLe"      4.84     2.38       8.68
"get0"                3.44     1.69       3.44
"<Anonymous>"         1.66     0.82       1.66
"length"              0.88     0.43       0.88
"is.matrix"           0.48     0.24       0.48
"do.call"             0.46     0.23     203.40
"is.numeric"          0.32     0.16       0.32
"is.atomic"           0.26     0.13       0.26
"match.fun"           0.06     0.03       0.06
                 total.pct
".Call"              79.54
"rmvn"               93.82
"matrix"              3.17
"FUN"               100.00
"lapply"            100.00
"getCallingDLLe"      4.27
"get0"                1.69
"<Anonymous>"         0.82
"length"              0.43
"is.matrix"           0.24
"do.call"            99.96
"is.numeric"          0.16
"is.atomic"           0.13
"match.fun"           0.03

$by.total
                       total.time total.pct
"FUN"                      203.48    100.00
"lapply"                   203.48    100.00
"do.call"                  203.40     99.96
"rmvn"                     190.90     93.82
".Call"                    161.84     79.54
"getCallingDLLe"             8.68      4.27
"matrix"                     6.46      3.17
"get0"                       3.44      1.69
"<Anonymous>"                1.66      0.82
"length"                     0.88      0.43
"is.matrix"                  0.48      0.24
"is.numeric"                 0.32      0.16
"is.atomic"                  0.26      0.13
"match.fun"                  0.06      0.03
"cmpfun"                     0.02      0.01
"compiler:::tryCmpfun"       0.02      0.01
"doTryCatch"                 0.02      0.01
"findLocalsList"             0.02      0.01
"findLocalsList1"            0.02      0.01
"funEnv"                     0.02      0.01
"make.functionContext"       0.02      0.01
"tryCatch"                   0.02      0.01
"tryCatchList"               0.02      0.01
"tryCatchOne"                0.02      0.01
                       self.time self.pct
"FUN"                       5.44     2.67
"lapply"                    4.96     2.44
"do.call"                   0.46     0.23
"rmvn"                     21.32    10.48
".Call"                   153.16    75.27
"getCallingDLLe"            4.84     2.38
"matrix"                    6.20     3.05
"get0"                      3.44     1.69
"<Anonymous>"               1.66     0.82
"length"                    0.88     0.43
"is.matrix"                 0.48     0.24
"is.numeric"                0.32     0.16
"is.atomic"                 0.26     0.13
"match.fun"                 0.06     0.03
"cmpfun"                    0.00     0.00
"compiler:::tryCmpfun"      0.00     0.00
"doTryCatch"                0.00     0.00
"findLocalsList"            0.00     0.00
"findLocalsList1"           0.00     0.00
"funEnv"                    0.00     0.00
"make.functionContext"      0.00     0.00
"tryCatch"                  0.00     0.00
"tryCatchList"              0.00     0.00
"tryCatchOne"               0.00     0.00

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 203.48
```

EDIT #2 - ideally this code will eventually go into a package, and so I need a way of speeding up this process, that can be present in code contributing to an R package

Comment: Did you profile your code to check what part is taking the longest? That'll answer questions related to the implementation. Depending on your hardware, you can run your draws in parallel, since everything can be done independently. Keep in mind you're running a task 2.5 million times, there is a lower bound on the time it'll take, but dividing in multiple independent chunks sounds the most reasonable approach timewise.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm new to profiling but here is some code I've just run - see edit in main section

Answer (score 1):

You can have a parallel solution with minimal changes to your code using the `furrr` package, for example.

```
#code needing speeding up
library(furrr)
plan(multisession)
system.time(test<-future_map(1:nPar,function(u){
  lapply(1:K,function(v){
    do.call(rbind,lapply(1:n[v],function(w){
      rmvn(n=1,
           mu=mu[[u]][[v]][w,],
           sigma=sigmamats[[u]])
    }))
  })
}))
```

resuts in

```
   user  system elapsed 
  0.815   0.163  14.501
```

while in your previous version, on my computer I had

```
   user  system elapsed 
 30.608   1.399  32.017
```

The results will highly depend on the number of cores of your CPU, but in general, you should have a performance improvement as the overhead introduced by parallelization is really small compared to computing time of the task, i.e., you spend a little more time to "split" the task between cores, but the time saved by each core executing only a fraction of the task is much more significant.

Comment: Would using plan() be an issue if the code is destined for an R package?  In the help file in plan in future package, under the section for package developers it says "do not call plan() in your code"?

Comment: I'd recommend against using `plan()` in a package, mainly because you don't know what kind of session, OS and hardware is being used. Alternatively, if `plan()` is not specified, `furrr` runs sequentially (which is your initial implementation). Therefore, you could use `future_map` in the package and tell the user to choose the `plan()` in documentation.

Comment: Is there an alternative to `plan()` from `furrr` that you would recommend for use within a package?

Comment: Another package for parallel computing, which I think is more appropriate for packages is `foreach`, but it should be a little more troublesome to implement. The `caret` package is one of the most popular machine learning packages in R and it uses `foreach` for parallelization. It also requires the user to setup the communication layer (usually it is just a simple function call, just like `plan()` on `furrr`).

Comment: Useful link for more information: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html